# VKSDK ошибка авторизации

Tags: java, android, android-vksdk

Имеется фрагмент, где я хочу пройти авторизацию.

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnSignIn;

    public static SignInFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        SignInFragment fragment = new SignInFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false);

        btnSignIn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Доступ к друзьям
                String[] scope = new String[]{
                        VKScope.FRIENDS
                };
                VKSdk.login(getActivity(), scope);

            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {

            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), res.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, FriendsFragment.newInstance())
                        .commit();

            }

            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Что-то пошло не так.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Ошибка", "ошибка");
        }
    }
}
```

Появляется окна запрашивания доступа (или авторизации), после подтверждения, просто закрывается окно VK, и все, хотя оно должно было провалиться в onResult или onError, и вывести Toast, но этого не происходит. Что я могу делать не так?

**Update**

Вывел в лог некоторую надпись, в первой строчке onActivityResult, так он туда вообще не проваливается

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то VKSDK не умеет выдавать результат во фрагмент. Т.е. да, оно должно в `onActivityResult` передавать исполнение, но не в метод фрагмента, но в метод активити. Вы, собственно, именно активити и передаёте в метод логина, засим в активити и переопределяйте `onActivityResult` и в нём и обрабатывайте результат. Или прокидывайте вызов вручную во фрагмент.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тогда для чего эта строчка: После этапа авторизации в Вашем Activity или Fragment будет вызван метод onActivityResult. Пример обработки приведен ниже

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я сначала хотел пробросить в другой Fragment, который бы чисто под авторизацию бы использовался для VK (чистый), но библиотека не поддерживает Fragment v4, а только Fragment, а он стал deprecated.

Comment: Здесь есть пример разраба https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/23, но они используют FragmentActivity. Я использую AppCompact, который наследует FragmentActivity, но я не вижу вообще кода в Activity, который бы управлял fragmentОм, да и классы, какие-то странные, уже наверно все методы переписали, за 5 лет

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перенес в Activity, заработало